# Logstash: Limit the message batch size to 10MB

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration

## The problem

I have a server with Logstash as a logging engine. The Logstash instance is configured to save its logs in an AWS Elasticsearch instance.

A few hours ago, I stopped seeing any logs in the ES cluster Kibana view:

[image]

The logstash log file has a lot of similar errors:

```
{:timestamp=>"2016-02-25T14:39:46.232000+0000", 
 :message=>"Got error to send bulk of actions: [413] 
 {\"Message\":\"Request size exceeded 10485760 bytes\"}", 
 :level=>:error}
```

I've talked to the AWS support, and they confirmed that their ES machines limit request size to 10MB.

## What have I tried

- Set `flush_size => 50` in the configuration

## The question

**How can I limit the Logstash request size to the 10MB limit enforced by ES?**

Answer (score 2):

I have had same issue, to fix that I set `flush_size => 100` in my output:elasticsearch configuration for logstash.

As a side note check "free storage space" in ES dashboard for your domain.

Edit:

for the first run after this change i run logstash from command line instead of as a demon:

```
/opt/logstash/bin/logstash -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/
```

Answer (score 1):

bug in github side: https://github.com/awslabs/logstash-output-amazon_es/issues/55

I have also lowered the `flush_size => 10`, but sometimes still had problems. So i when to track the source, created several outputs, add IDs to them to help tracking and added a fallback size:  `retry_max_items => 1`

Then i used the logstash API, when logstash was not outputing any more events, to find the outputs that were locking up:

`curl -XGET 'localhost:9600/_node/stats/pipeline?pretty' -s | jq . | awk 'BEGIN {FS="{|}|: |\," } /"in":/ { i=$2 ; next }; /"out":/ { o=$2 ; next } /"id":/ { id=$2 }; /name/ { print $0, i-o , id }  '`

The output with `in-out` greater than zero are the ones that are unable to flush to amazon_es

With this i found the source of the problem and that i had events with almost 10MB. So my solution was to truncated them to a sane size and finally fix this.

So my setup is now something like this:

```
filter {
(...)
# truncate big fields events to ~1MB
# need the logstash-filter-truncate plugin
  truncate {
    length_bytes => "1048576"
    fields => [ "message", "error" , "error_orig" ]
  }
(...)
}
output {
(...)
      amazon_es {
        id => "producer"
        hosts => "${ES_HOSTNAME}"
        index => "logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}-%{[type]}-%{[environment]}"
        document_type => "%{[type]}"
        flush_size => 10
        # if still fails, flush one by one until success
        retry_max_items => 1
      }
(...)
}
```

Hope this helps someone with the same problem

Comment: For those that copied & pasted the above like I did and wondered why it didn't seem to work, 1073741824 bytes is ~1GB. 1MB in bytes is actually 1048576.

Comment: thanks @smilin_stan, i have corrected the above example. in my real life config i have a 128k limit, so i also didn't noticed my the error :)